# Disagreeing with a duplicate flag

Tags: discussion

I've recently been looking at [this question about breaking out of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293288/breaking-2-nested-loops-at-once/23293726), which has been flagged up as a possible duplicate of [this question about labelled statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf) - a flag with which I don't agree. *As a user that isn't yet able to cast open/close votes on flagged questions*<sup>†</sup>, how should I best approach this?

Should I:

- comment to say that I don't agree with the duplicate flag?
- ignore it and wait to see what the community decides?
- do something else entirely?

<sup>†</sup> Obviously if you have the requisite reputation to vote then that's the appropriate thing to do!

Comment: It currently just seems to be a flag. There is no active close vote on it, so it's not on its way to being closed just yet. You've left a comment, which is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Bart Ah, fair enough, perhaps I've not fully understood what flagging does in that case. I can't yet see open/close votes either, so I can't tell if there's an active vote going on! If you want to post this as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing the question apparently just had a duplicate flag on it. There were no close votes, so there wasn't an immediate danger of the question being closed as a duplicate. It will appear in review queues to have those with sufficient privileges establish whether it's a duplicate or not.

However, if you see such a flag comment and you disagree with it, you can always comment, as you have. A comment along the lines of "It's different from that question because ..." is just fine, which you've done. So well done. Just make sure you don't leave a comment like "no it's not" or something similar, because that won't achieve a whole lot. But I'd say you did well.